# How to change the datatable column id to int(typeconversion)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the datatable :

```
 DataTable dtemp = new DataTable();

 dtemp = objDB.SelectEmployeeSalaryByYear11(Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue));
```

I am trying this but showing the problem..

```
   Int32 dtemps = int.Parse(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());

and
 Int32 dtemps = Convert.ToInt32(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
```

so how to convert the datatatble column id to int??

hERE IS THE TOTAL CODE:

```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        string upld = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in grdSalary.Rows)
            {
                DataTable dtemp = new DataTable();
                dtemp = objDB.SelectEmployeeSalaryByYear11(Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue));
                Int32 dtemps = Convert.ToInt32(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                Int32 empId = Convert.ToInt32(grdSalary.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["EID"]);
                DataTable dtempcount = new DataTable();
                dtempcount = objDB.SelectEmployeeSalaryByEmpIDYear11(Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue), empId);

                TextBox txtjan = gvr.FindControl("txtjan") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtfeb = gvr.FindControl("txtfeb") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtmarch = gvr.FindControl("txtmarch") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtapril = gvr.FindControl("txtapril") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtmay = gvr.FindControl("txtmay") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtjune = gvr.FindControl("txtjune") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtjuly = gvr.FindControl("txtjuly") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtaug = gvr.FindControl("txtaug") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtsept = gvr.FindControl("txtsept") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtoct = gvr.FindControl("txtoct") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtnov = gvr.FindControl("txtnov") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtdec = gvr.FindControl("txtdec") as TextBox;


                if (dtempcount.Rows.Count == 0)
                {

                    Int32 Intuserid = objDB.insert_updateSalary(0, Convert.ToInt32(grdSalary.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["EID"]), Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue),
                        txtjan.Text, txtfeb.Text, txtmarch.Text, txtapril.Text, txtmay.Text, txtjune.Text, txtjuly.Text, txtaug.Text,
                        txtsept.Text, txtoct.Text, txtnov.Text, txtdec.Text);


                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                       // Int32 Intuserid = objDB.insert_updateSalary(Convert.ToInt32(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"]), Convert.ToInt32(grdSalary.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["EID"]), Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue),
                       //txtjan.Text, txtfeb.Text, txtmarch.Text, txtapril.Text, txtmay.Text, txtjune.Text, txtjuly.Text, txtaug.Text,
                       //txtsept.Text, txtoct.Text, txtnov.Text, txtdec.Text);
                        Int32 Intuserid = objDB.insert_updateSalary(int.Parse(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(grdSalary.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["EID"]), Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue),
                      txtjan.Text, txtfeb.Text, txtmarch.Text, txtapril.Text, txtmay.Text, txtjune.Text, txtjuly.Text, txtaug.Text,
                      txtsept.Text, txtoct.Text, txtnov.Text, txtdec.Text);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I WANT TO UPDATE OR INSERT DATA INTO DATATABSE..

the problem is that while  Int32 dtemps getting zero shows input string was not in correct format..

Comment: I think your id may be null or empty So check this before convert to integer or set default value

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone your datatable and then change the type of the column like

```
DataTable mydt = dtemp.Clone();
mydt.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
foreach (DataRow row in dtemp.Rows) 
{
    mydt.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: sir can you explain me??

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTable is probably empty, that's why it doesn't work.

Check Row `i` is less than the RowCount, eg:

```
if (dtempcount.Rows.Count > i)
```

Comment: What's the exception? Please [edit] you're question with it.

Comment: And the Id column is an Integer, not a GUID? Can you please show a screenshot with the code control halted on a break point on the line that causes the error **Int32 dtemps = Convert.ToInt32(dtemp.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());** with the mouse cursor over dTemps variable with the tooltip object browser expanded showing the DataTable has rows.

Comment: {"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."}

Comment: Sir actually the problem is   else
                {
                    try
                    {
                      here..i want to simply insert or update by using stored procedure..then error comes out  
{"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."} and value will be inserted to database duplicate.

Comment: See the Table is empty.. It's probably because the SelectedValue starts at 1970 or something so your trying to fetch year 0046 from the dB

Comment: Just Convert.ToInt instead of TryParse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121592/discussion-between-manoj-maharana-and-jeremy-thompson).

Comment: sir i have done..but the same problem..goes to catch block

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot as per above instructions, bit hard to help without it

Comment: sir can you come to the chat??